# Dividing two gamma distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution

I am trying to determine the distribution function of 2 random variables X and Y such that X/Y. I have determined that X~gamma with parameters alpha = 3/2 and beta = 4 and Y~gamma with parameters alpha = 1 and beta = 4. I am stuck with how to combine these distributions. Is there any theorem that relates to dividing two gamma functions and how it changes it's parameters?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: "Such that X/Y"... *what*?

Comment: Search for keywords: ["change of variables theorem"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=change+of+variable),  ["Jacobian formula"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jacobian), ["convolution formula"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=convolution+integral)...